# Problem with jquery-droppable in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I have a simple application that users jquery-ui's draggable and droppable. In Firefox, it works perfectly. In Chrome, however, I'm having problems.

This is the code:

```
$(".cell").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
           var originalTarget = event.originalTarget;
           ...
         }
});
```

In Chrome the 'event' object is of type 'Object' (using Chrome Dev Kit), and event.originalTarget is 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the draggable element, use `ui.draggable` (this is a jQuery object). To get the droppable, use `$(this)`. See the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Droppable#event-drop) on the `drop` event.

```
var draggable = ui.draggable[0];
var droppable = $(this)[0];
```

Comment: But target and originalTarget mean two different things - target is the where you are dragging TO, and originalTarget is WHAT you are dragging to it.

Comment: Thanks, I updated your question with the code I ended up using (array access [0] to get the actual element).